# How do I find the latest time for each date in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have this array in JSON format:

```
var result=[
    {
        "index": 13,
        "id": 1122,
```

```
*
```

Comment: What do you mean by most recent time? Is there a threshold that needs to be met or you just need to output all the times within the specific date

Comment: So if you look at the array of JSON above, for example, for result[0] and result[1], the date times are 11/12/2020 1:59 and 11/12/2020 3:15 respectively. 

I only want to output result[1], because 3:15 is more recent for that day compared to 1:59. (And I want to output the most recent time for other days as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach below:

- get a unique list of only the dates from the array i.e. dd/mm/yyyy
- for each date in the unique list, create a sorted array per the times for that date
- return the 0th item from that sorted array for that date

Example code:

```js
var result = [
  {
    "index": 13,
    "id": 1122,
    "price": 100,
    "dateTime": "11/12/2020 1:59"
  },
  {
    "index": 14,
    "id": 1122,
    "price": 300,
    "dateTime": "11/12/2020 3:15"
  },
  {
    "index": 15,
    "id": 1122,
    "price": 314,
    "dateTime": "11/13/2020 2:20"
  },
  {
    "index": 16,
    "id": 1122,
    "price": 280,
    "dateTime": "11/13/2020 2:23"
  }
];

// get a list of the dates in result
// nothing fancy - the date is just a key
var dates = result.map(k => k.dateTime.substr(0, 10));
// get unique dates from this array
var uniqueDates = Array.from(new Set(dates));
// for each unique date, sort the times descending
// return the first item (latest) for that date
var filtered = uniqueDates.map(ud => {
  var dateItems = result.filter(d => d.dateTime.substr(0, 10) == ud);
  dateItems.sort((a, b) => (new Date(b.dateTime)).getTime() - (new Date(a.dateTime)).getTime());
  return dateItems[0];
});
// output
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the Array on the `Date` value of `dateTime`, write a result array with dates-only as keys, retrieve the values of the result.

The `TypeError`, by the way, is because you should check for `i + 1` being smaller than `result.length` in the loop (this will be `falsy` for the last element within the loop. In that case `new Date(result[i+1].dateTime)` will throw the error).

```js
// initialize log helper
const log = Logger();

// create an empty Object
const result = {};

// sort data ascending
const dataSorted = getData().sort((a, b) =>
  new Date(a.dateTime) - new Date(b.dateTime));

// add to result with datestring as key. 
// The value with the most recent date will be preserved
// because key values are unique (so equal keys are overwritten)
dataSorted.forEach(v => result[new Date(v.dateTime).toDateString()] = v);

// the values of [result] contain the most recent records per date
log(Object.values(result));

// this can also be a one liner, using a reducer method
const resultX = Object.values(
  getData()
    .sort( (a, b) => new Date(a.dateTime) - new Date(b.dateTime) )
    .reduce( (acc, value) => 
      ({...acc, [new Date(value.dateTime).toDateString()]: value}), {} )
);

log(`\n**from reducer`, resultX);

function getData() {
  return [{
      "index": 13,
      "id": 1122,
      "price": 100,
      "dateTime": "11/12/2020 1:59"
    },
    {
      "index": 14,
      "id": 1122,
      "price": 300,
      "dateTime": "11/12/2020 3:15"
    },
    {
      "index": 15,
      "id": 1122,
      "price": 314,
      "dateTime": "11/13/2020 2:20"
    },
    {
      "index": 16,
      "id": 1122,
      "price": 280,
      "dateTime": "11/13/2020 2:23"
    }
  ];
}

function Logger() {
  const report = document.querySelector("#report") || 
    document.body.insertAdjacentElement(
      "beforeend",
      Object.assign(document.createElement("pre"), {id: "report"}));
  return (...args) => args.forEach(stuff =>
      report.textContent += (stuff instanceof Object 
        ? JSON.stringify(stuff, null, 2) : stuff) + "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data based on date like,

```
const groups = data.reduce((groups, currVal) => {
  const date = currVal.dateTime.split(' ')[0];
  if (!groups[date]) {
    groups[date] = [];
  }
  groups[date].push(currVal);
  return groups;
}, {});
```

> -> Here we split the date and and time part using `split(' ')` and took the date alone separately and form a group,
>
> ```
> const date = currVal.dateTime.split(' ')[0];
> ```

And then you can get the recent date and time using the method,

```
groups[item].reduce((a, b) => (a.dateTime > b.dateTime ? a : b));
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
const data = [
    {
        "index": 13,
        "id": 1122,
        "price": 100,
        "dateTime": "11/12/2020 1:59"
    },
    {
        "index": 14,
        "id": 1122,
        "price": 300,
        "dateTime": "11/12/2020 3:15"
    },
    {
        "index": 15,
        "id": 1122,
        "price": 314,
        "dateTime": "11/13/2020 2:20"
    },
    {
        "index": 16,
        "id": 1122,
        "price": 280,
        "dateTime": "11/13/2020 2:23"
    }
];


//Group the data based on date
const groups = data.reduce((groups, currVal) => {
  const date = currVal.dateTime.split(' ')[0];
  if (!groups[date]) {
    groups[date] = [];
  }
  groups[date].push(currVal);
  return groups;
}, {});

//Get the recent date and time based on each group
const result = [];
Object.keys(groups).filter(item => {
  const newData = groups[item].reduce((a, b) => (a.dateTime > b.dateTime ? a : b));
  result.push(newData);
});

console.log(result)
```